# C++ templating for vector math generating GLSL

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to come up with a C++ templating design pattern that would allow me to write C++ looking code like this the example below, that is able to both generate a string representation of the operations (like GLSL), and compute the actual results.

```
template<typename T>
vec3<T> make_effect(const vec3<T> &color, const mat3<T> &fx_matrix) {
    return sin(fx_matrix * color);
}

// I should of course define a sin function using this style of templating.
```

(This math in this example makes little sense, but it gives a hint of what I'm after.)

Note that there is a template parameter `T`. The thing is that I would like to be able to with this single instance of code, produce the GLSL code, AND perform actual calculations on CPU, depending on the template parameter.

For example, in case of GLSL as a target:

```
vec3<GLSL> expression = make_effect(vec3<GLSL>(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.1f), some_matrix);
std::string glsl_code = expression.to_string();
// would be:
assert(glsl_code == "sin(some_matrix * vec3(1.0, 0.4, 0.1))");
```

Or, in case of CPU-side calculations:

```
vec3<CPU> result = make_effect(vec3<CPU>(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.1f), some_matrix);
// now: result.x(), result.y(), result.z() contain the 
// actual values of the calculation
```

How should I approach such a thing? Does this have a name? Do similar solutions already exist?

Also note that I don't want to calculate anything in case of the GLSL variant. I only need the code, to be able to generate a shader for the GPU.
Extensibility to new implementations, for example Direct X shaders is a plus.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I suspect you might be looking for [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: The same code should generate a string of GLSL code, and be able to produce the actual numerical result. This by instantiating it twice, with a different template parameter.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux yes, I can foresee that being feasible this way. Quite the task, but feasible :)

Comment: The article I cite mentions `Vec` and `VecExpression`. You'd basically have `vec3<CPU>` specialization behave like `Vec`, and `vec3<GLSL>` specialization behave like `VecExpression`. Though I must admit I don't understand the ultimate goal of the exercise.

Comment: Isn't it just easier to write out the Shader files?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do it.

For all datatypes define a struct supporting operations like in GLSL. Note that it inherits from the template parameter `B` (which stands for "backend"). Also note that all functions are by default `delete`d. Example below is the interface for a `float` (shortened to `fl` to avoid C++ keyword collision):

```
template <typename B>
struct fl : public B {
    fl(B b) : B(b) {}
    fl(float x) = delete;

    operator float() const = delete;

    fl<B> operator+(const fl<B> &rhs) const = delete;
    fl<B> operator*(const fl<B> &rhs) const = delete;
    fl<B> operator-(const fl<B> &rhs) const = delete;
    fl<B> operator/(const fl<B> &rhs) const = delete;

    fl<B> operator-() const = delete;

    vec2<B> operator*(const vec2<B> &rhs) const = delete;
    vec3<B> operator*(const vec3<B> &rhs) const = delete;
};
```

Now we will define a backend to use as `B`, for GLSL:

```
class GLSL {
    std::string expr;

  public:
    operator std::string() const { return expr; }
    operator const char *() const { return expr.c_str(); }

    const std::string &str() const { return expr; }

    GLSL(const std::string &str) : expr(str) {}
    GLSL(const char *str) : expr(str) {}
};
```

Then, we will implement the GLSL backend template specialisation. For example the `fl + fl` operation in GLSL:

```
template <>
inline fl<GLSL> fl<GLSL>::operator +(const fl<GLSL> &rhs) const {
    return fl<GLSL>("(" + str() + "+" + rhs.str() + ")");
}
```

And many more implementations come here as well.

Now we do something similar for the CPU backend (using Eigen):

```
class CPU {
  public:
    union {
        float _fl;
        Eigen::Vector2f _vec2;
        Eigen::Vector3f _vec3;
        struct {
            float _x, _y, _z;
        };
    };

    CPU(float x) { _fl = x; }
    CPU(Eigen::Vector2f x) { _vec2 = x; }
    CPU(Eigen::Vector3f x) { _vec3 = x; }

    CPU(const CPU &orig) { _vec3 = orig._vec3; }
};
```

And the `fl + fl` implementation:

```
template <>
inline fl<CPU> fl<CPU>::operator +(const fl<CPU> &rhs) const {
    return fl<CPU>(_fl + rhs._fl);
}
```

And this for all possible operators (binary and unary), functions, etc... Note that I used a lot of C preprocessor macros to save a lot of typing work. Also swizzling for vector types is completely implemented using these functions like `xxx()`.

---

Now as a demo:

```
using namespace vecmath;

template <typename B>
vec3<B> make_effect(vec3<B> a, vec3<B> b) {
    return pow(a, b).yzx() + sin(a);
}

TEST(vecmath_demo, demo_01) {
    // GLSL
    vec3<GLSL> g_a("a");
    vec3<GLSL> g_b("b");
    vec3<GLSL> expr = make_effect(g_a, g_b);

    std::cout << "GLSL: " << expr.str() << std::endl;

    // CPU
    vec3<CPU> c_a(2.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f);
    vec3<CPU> c_b(0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);
    vec3<CPU> result = make_effect(c_a, c_b);

    std::cout << "CPU: " << ((Eigen::Vector3f)result).transpose() << std::endl;

    SUCCEED();
}
```

Prints:

```
GLSL: (pow(a, b).yzx+sin(a))
CPU:  4.9093  8.2432 1.14112
```

Comment: This might not be a problem for your use case, but effects with intermediate results, like `auto t = a * b; return pow(a, t).yzx() + sin(t);` would yield duplicate substitutions of `t` in generating backend, i.e. `GLSL: (pow(a, a*b).yzx+sin(a*b))`

Comment: @yurikilochek Yes, indeed! I'm planning on introducing some system with locals and dependencies.